# Beginner GXT issues

Tags: gwt, gxt

We have a working web application, which has been developed with ExtJS for client side, and Struts, Spring, Hibernate for server side. now, we are considering to migrate to GXT (or may be GWT itself). The thing is I'm very new to GWT/GXT. and we are trying to decide whether we go down this road or not.

1) Until now, we have 2 domains for our web-app. one is that the application (Struts+...) have been deployed to, and the other is mainly a cookie-less custom CDN. The transfer between client and server is mostly XHR requests, sending/receiving JSON and/or JSONP. But with the new approach ahead of us, I began to understand that we are supposed to have only ONE domain, for the whole GXT application. Is it correct or I forgot to consider something here?

and if not, Is it possible that we deployed just part of the application (i.e. com.ourcompany.webapp.gxt.server.*) to the main server, and the contents that have been compiled and generated by the GWT compiler to the other CDN-like domain?

2) The other big issue we are facing is that the current application is consists of mostly 3 huge modules. One is responsible for "SignIn", the other is for "Webtop", and the third one is "Modules which each users has access to". The latter has been generated on the server due to "access rights" of each users, and obviously could be different from one user to the other.

The only thing I could find on this matter, which might be related is [Code Splitting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting). Although I'm not totally sure if this would be the right solution for this.

We want that the application, on Start Up, checks whether user has been logged in or not. if not, loads the SignIn sets of javascript files (i.e webapp.signin.nocache.js), then after user has entered the correct username/password, unloads this signin file and loads webtop.nocache.js AND modules.nocache.js.

I would be really appreciated if you could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

1) If your GWT app is loaded from a different domain than you have to face the same origin policy. You can not do a xhr to a different domain. You could use the [ScriptTagProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/data/ScriptTagProxy.html) to get around this. But it does not feel very netural.

2) You can use CodeSplitting in order to automatically load a particular part of your application dynamically. All you have to do is to warp your splitt point into an async call. 
A detailed [compile report](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport) gives you a pretty good overview how well code splitting is working.

But CodeSplitting does not unload already loaded code. If its really importend to do so you have to redirect the user to another url in order to load the appropriate user depended module.
Once Javascript code has been loaded and executed its impossible to remove the code from the browsers memory.

Grettings,
Peter

Comment: Thank you for your response Peter. but 1) So is it "practically not a good way" to use two different domains? 2) Is it possible to generate modules.nocache.js for each user at some split point on the fly?

Comment: 1) exactly; 2) If you have code like if(userA) { startUserAModul();} else if(userB) { startUserBModul();} aso. and put a "CodeSplitting" point into the startUserXModul methods gwt should automatically create additional Javascript files for each "modul". These JS files are automatically loaded when you call the appropriate modul. The detailed gwt compile report gives you a lot of intormation about the code splitting.